# Cursor crash on android application

Tags: database, list, cursors

Hello everyware i'm envelop an application for extract data from local ip database, where application start the application crash at press button from extract an article, the interessing code error is a subcall at mainactivity2:

```
    public  List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + KEY_ARTICOLO;
        Cursor cursor  = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        return labels;
        }
```

Error is:

```
Process: spa.a1926.federighi.blancmariclo, PID: 8203
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
    at spa.a1926.federighi.blancmariclo.MainActivity2$GestioneDB.getAllLabels(MainActivity2.java:131)
    at spa.a1926.federighi.blancmariclo.MainActivity2$1.onClick(MainActivity2.java:50)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
10-30 10:53:22.815 1536-3316/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
10-30 10:53:22.815 1536-3316/system_process E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
```

The call in main(mainactivity2) is:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
                GestioneDB db = new GestioneDB(getApplicationContext());
                List<String> parolemenu = db.getAllLabels();
                ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity2.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parolemenu);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
        });
```